# Compiling Rust static library and using it in C++: undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker, rust, static-libraries

I'm trying to compile a `static` library in Rust, and then use it in my C++ code (note this is about calling Rust from C++ and not the other way around). I went over all the tutorials I could find online, and replies to similar questions, and I'm obviously doing something wrong, though I can't see what.

I created a minimal example for my problem :

**1. Cargo.toml :**

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"

[lib]
name = "hello_in_rust_lib"
path = "src/lib.rs"
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[dependencies]
```

**2. lib.rs :**

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_world_in_rust() {
    println!("Hello World, Rust here!");
}
```

**3. hello_world_in_cpp.cpp :**

```
extern void hello_world_in_rust();

int main() {
    hello_world_in_rust();
}
```

To build the library, in my rust directory I ran :

> cargo build --lib

(which went fine)
I proceeded to run, in my C++ folder :

> clang++ hello_world_in_cpp.cpp -o hello.out -L ../hello_world/target/release/ -lhello_in_rust_lib

Which resulted in the following error :

> /tmp/hello_world_in_cpp-cf3577.o: In function `main` :
>
> hello_world_in_cpp.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `hello_world_in_rust()`

Comment: Is this the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/43866969/3005167?

Comment: @kazemakase unfortunately it isn't, as far as I could see. This is C++, and I tried switching to g++ (instead of clang++), but it had no effect.

Comment: @Shir Intuitively I'd guess C++ or C does not matter.... wait, don't you need to specify `extern "C"` in C++?

Comment: @VTT I tried dynamic libraries (namely - linking with an .so file I created by adding "crate-type = ["dylib"]" to my cargo file. It resulted in the exact same "undefined reference" error on compilation.

Comment: @kazemakase OMG. That worked! Thank you.

Comment: good to hear :) In that case, I guess we can say that the question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44056461/3005167)?

Comment: @kazemakase I wouldn't say that. It explains why your suggestion works, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call C++ functions from library in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105186/how-can-i-call-c-functions-from-library-in-rust)

Comment: @Stargateur no, it’s the other way around. This question is about calling a Rust library in C++.

Comment: @Shir Oh, you very right, but the answer will be very close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name mangling in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is not standardized, therefore `void hello_world_in_rust()` might have a different linkage compared to [c](/questions/tagged/c). You can force the same C linkage in both languages by using `extern "C"` as part of the functions signature/prototype:

```
extern "C" void hello_world_in_rust();
```